# Use javascript to inject rel="canonical"

Tags: javascript

For a reason I can't modify the html head for the rel="canonical".

How to I inject rel="canonical" using javascript and does search engine accept the this type of injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the DOM within the `<head>` tag just as you can anything else.  However, it won't do you much good.  Crawlers/bots generally don't run your JavaScript.