# AMP Discovery by Injecting <link> on canonical with javascript

Tags: amp-html

I am researching providing some AMP Pages for my eCommerce site.  I do not think that the CMS vendor had the ability to add dynamic content to the , So i will have trouble getting the Amp pages discoverabel in this senerio.

I was hopping to Inject the Link

link rel="amphtml" as indicated on [The Discovery Docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery) with JavaScript, but this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911372/use-javascript-to-inject-rel-canonical) article of a few years ago indicates that google will not render the javascript and will not be able to dymamicly generate injected Head/link tag.

Is this still true. Any thoughts from the community on a possible solution.

Comment: Crawlers typically don't run your JavaScript. Is there no other way for you to get content into the head? Contact the provider perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to repose for internet posterity.  At this time it is not possible to use JavaScript to dynamically inject (link rel="amphtml") to have your AMP content recognized by google.

You will have to have enough control over your page that you have the ability to have the ink rel="amphtml" rendered inline with the initial server load.